# How do you disable session timeout in Wildfly

Tags: session, wildfly, session-timeout

I am running Wildfly 18 in standalone mode.

I have the following in jboss-web.xml in the WEB-INF directory of my app.war directory.

```
<web-app>
   <session-config>
      <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Wildfly sessions are still timing out.

How do you disable the session timeout in Wildfly?

Comment: How are you determining that the session timed out?

Comment: Why are you trying to disable the timeout? If you are wanting something more persistent than a session, it would suggest you shouldn't be using a session to store that data. By very definition, a session has a beginning and an end. If you are trying to disable the clean-up of sessions, that would suggest you have data in there that should perhaps be in a more persistent storage than the session

Comment: The user receives a "Session information has expired or is invalid"  on a jsp try catch statement.

Comment: Some users are more inquiry type users. They login in in the morning an throughout the day, they may need to look something up. If they are idle for a while - I haven't pinned down just how long - they get this message.